# JPQL Query returns object with no field names

Tags: java, json, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard and Hibernate.

I got this JPQL query:

```
String queryString = "select u.portalUserId, p.personName, p.personMobile, p.personEmail, u.portalUsertype, p.personNotes "
                  + "FROM Persons p, PortalUsers u WHERE p.personId = u.portalUserPersonId";
```

This is a simple join between 2 entities and get some info on users.

The way I run it is like that:

```
Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString); 
List<PortalUserBasicUserInfo> l = q.list();
```

PortalUserBasicUserInfo is a class which has all the fields of the select clause.

When I run the query, I get only the values of each field but without the field names. For example, a result I receive is:

```
"[[2,\"\",null,null,\"MANAGER\",null]]"
```

This will not work since I want to return a JSON result with field names. How do I add the fields name so someone who is reading the json can parse it properly?

Comment: Why not add a new entry to the JSON for the column headers?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Modify your JSON by adding an entry for the headers.

Comment: The json is created automatically from the object of the list. Thats why I need the list itself to return with the same title as the select fields.

Comment: Seems like more of a json issue than hibernate. Hibernate has retrieved your objects so your problem lies in serializing the object properly. Post the "to json" code instead.

Comment: Its not a JSON problem since the list returns from Hibernate as a list of Object[]. The Json string represent accurately what is returning from Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did was changing to query to return the type I need:

```
String queryString = "select new com.myPackage.Users.PortalUserBasicUserInfo(u.portalUserId ,p.personName, p.personMobile, p.personEmail, u.portalUserStatus, u.portalUsertype, p.personNotes) "
                  + "FROM Persons p, PortalUsers u WHERE p.personId = u.portalUserPersonId";
```

Notice the `new com.myPackage.Users.PortalUserBasicUserInfo`. This has created a list of the correct type I expected it to be.